# Kadanes algorithm implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I just wanted to ask the following question. I have solved Kadanes algorithm using the recursive approach as shown below. The implementation works

```java
 public class Kadane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr =  {-2, -5, 6, -2, -3, 1, 5, -6};
        Kadane k = new Kadane();
        System.out.println(k.calculate(arr, 0, 0));
    }

    public int calculate(int[] arr, int pointer, int sum) {
        if(pointer >= arr.length )
            return sum;

        return Math.max(sum, Math.max(calculate(arr, pointer+1, sum+arr[pointer]), calculate(arr, pointer+1, 0)));
    }
}
```

My question is whether the way I am using recursion(top down) is correct or should recursion by definition should always be bottom up? Is this approach correct logically even though implementation wise it seems fine?

Comment: The implementation is correct, but the time complexity is awful (O(2^n) I think). You can convert it into an O(n) algorithm by using a technique called Dynamic Programming. Is this homework?

Comment: @log N Is a dp solution an option for you?

Comment: I find the wording strange. Algorithms don't get solved. An algorithm solves a problem; the execution of an implementation solves a problem instance. The problem solved by *Kadane's algorithm* is the [maximum subarray problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane's_algorithm). I think using recursion with the biggest/original problem instance handled in the outermost call natural. There are tail recursive variants of simple loops, e.g., computing *fib(n)* sort of fast; I find them atypical.